# Execute CGI file without extension

Tags: linux, apache, tcl, cgi

I am new to CGI or Apache.

I am trying to install an application called as mooshak.

The installation is finishing fine. But when I open the local site, it simply downloads the file instead of executing it.

When I open `http://localhost/~mooshak/cgi-bin/execute`, it simply downloads the file as shown:

```
#!/bin/sh
# the next line restarts using tclsh \
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/contrib/bin  ; exec tclsh "$0" "$@"

#-*-Mode: TCL; iso-accents-mode: t;-*-  

set errorCode NONE

cd ../..

lappend auto_path packages

source .config

execute::command_line
```

My `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf` file looks like this :

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        <Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin>
                Options +ExecCGI -Includes -Indexes
                SetHandler cgi-script
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
         Options -Includes -Indexes
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /home/*/public_html/cgi-bin>
         Options +ExecCGI -Includes -Indexes
         SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>
```

And give to script `chmod +x`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/urs/lib/cgi-bin` for cgi-scripts. Every thing else will give you a haedache if you not know what to do.

The cgi-scripts need to be **executable** and **readable** for the user `www-data`

For Apache version >=2.2 you will need to add an entry in `/etc/apache2/conf-available`. My config looks like this ...

```
admin@suse:~$ cat /etc/apache2/conf-available/cgi-bin.conf 
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            AllowOverride AuthConfig
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Suleiman's Heimat 2.0"
                AuthBasicProvider file
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/passwd
                Require valid-user
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>
```

These are the default settings for Debian systems, and additional password protection.

Then you call `a2enconf cgi-bin`.

This has nothing to do with `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` ! I cant find a reason to put cgi-code in there. Instead you will need to activate the common-gateway-interface via

```
a2enmod cgi
```

This will put a entry into `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled`.

Last but not least, you need to restart the server via `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

There you go.
Hope this will help.

---

**Addition**

You should run `apache2ctl configtest` to check your configuration, before restarting the server!

`/var/log/apache2/` has also good info when something goes south.
You can also use the command `systemctl status apache2.service` to check the status of your service and `journalctl -b -n 30 -u apache2.service` to get the last 30 protocol entries.